# How would RESTful API for Parse work for HTML application?

Tags: cross-domain, parse-platform, restful-architecture

Parse is a Backend-as-Service platform that offers [RESTful API](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest) for data storage and query.  It seems very appealing for front-end or mobile developer and allows them to focus on business logic without worry about those troublesome back-end technologies.

The RESTful endpoint looks something like this:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

If I want to use this on my site, say awesomehtmlsite.com, wouldn't the request be blocked by cross domain restrictions?  Same would hold true for the [Javascript API](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide).

Can someone explain to me how I can utilize the RESTful API or the Javascript API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responses to calls to the Parse javascript API include the following header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

This allows it to be used cross-domain. You should just be able to follow the JavaScript guide/API that Parse provides, without worrying about cross-domain issues.

Comment: Wouldn't this then mean anyone could update my data as long as they know my client key, which they can easily obtain by view source?

Comment: Parse provides pretty granular permissions that you can apply to objects, combined with a user account/authentication system. This allows you to lock down who can modify data. Take a look at the [Parse Security Guide](https://parse.com/docs/data#security), it should answer your questions.